# Convert string base64 to file vb c#

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, filestream

I have an string in vb this string is a file converted to base64 and I want to convert to a file, is there any function in vb to do it?

Comment: You could try converting your string to a byte array and then writing that to a file using a filestream object.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(path, Convert.FromBase64String(value)) ought to get you somewhere.  Kinda important to learn how to glue the .net parts together, you'll need to work on that.

Comment: You want to actually convert it back to the original form, or save the encoded string to a file?  One sentence questions often lack clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File.WriteAllBytes but first decode the Base64-String.

You could also (not recommended) decode the string and save it via "MemoryStream" as an executable (or whatever the filetype is).